# Can I use "where" with "trend"?

Tags: grammar, relative-adverbs

> The trend *where* teenagers dream of influencer fame has become more and more popular.

> The trend *that* teenagers dream of influencer fame has become more and more popular.

Are these sentences correct? Trend is not a place but I think it sounds natural to use "where" to refer to it.

Comment: Both are possible. The difference is a grammatical one. The first is a relative construction in which "where teenagers dream ..." is a relative clause modifying "trend". In the second "that teenagers dream ..." is a declarative content clause functioning as complement of "trend".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Where" is correct in this case.

"That" is incorrect because "that" always functions as a noun in relative clauses, but in this case, the phrase "teenagers dream of influencer fame" isn't missing any nouns, so "that" breaks the grammar.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the OP's second example. It's not a relative construction: "that" is a subordinator introducing the declarative content clause _that teenagers dream of influencer fame_ functioing as complement (not modifier) of trend".

Comment: @BillJ Interesting...  I see it now, but in my ear it doesn't work with "trend" in the same way it works with, say, "belief": "*The **belief** that teenagers dream of influencer fame...*"